# Jagged Simplex noise

Tags: noise

I've decided to go with a simplex noise instead of Perlin noise. This is the noise implementation I've ported from Java to C#: [SimplexNoise](http://code.google.com/p/toxiclibs/source/browse/trunk/toxiclibs/src.core/toxi/math/noise/SimplexNoise.java?r=188)

[image: Smooth Perlin noise] Smooth Unity Perlin noise

[image: Jagged Simplex noise]Jagged Simplex noise

How can I make the simplex noise look more "smooth", just like Unity's Perlin noise? Blur is one solution, but is there an easier way to tweak some parameter of simplex noise? I want my simplex noise to look similar to Perlin noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplex noise looks wrong: I suspect you haven't normalised it into the (0,1) range, so some of the noise is getting truncated to zero.

They should look pretty similar, see the images on this page:

- http://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/perlin-noise-vs-simplex-noise/

Comment: I was able to fix it. You were right, the returned noise was in range [-1;1], what I had to do is noise = (noise + 1.0f) * .5f;